# Rails, search via ransacker

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ransack

My app has a Shop model

```
# Table name: shops
#
#  id                             :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                           :string
#  address                        :string
```

Currently, I have written a code to search for shop by a combination of their id, name and address using the following code(which works perfectly):

```
  ransacker :search_name, formatter: proc { |v| v.mb_chars.downcase.to_s } do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('LOWER',
                                   [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws',
                                                                   [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' '), parent.table[:name], parent.table[:address], parent.table[:id]])])
  end
```

The corresponding view for the shops looks like this:

```
  = search_form_for @search, remote: true do |f|
    .input-group
      = f.text_field :search_name_cont
      = button_tag(type: 'submit')
```

And the controller:

```
 def index
   @search = Shop.search(params[:q])    
   @shops = @search.result.page(params[:page])
 end
```

Shop model also has_many tags.

When using the search form I would like to be able to find a Shop with address="London, 32 Russell Square" and which has a tag with name = "shoes" by searching for "london shoes".

Any idea how to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: `I can find a shop which is in London and has a tag "shoes" by searching for "london shoes"`, didn't understand it. What do you want here?

Comment: You are quoting half of the sentence. However, I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: So you want to search for "london shoes" and have it return all shops that have "shoes" in the name and "london" in the address?

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary to use ransack, however.